# UPDATE statment with CHARINDEX is producing an error and not updating anything

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to replace a long string that always appears at the end of a string of data.

This string of data at the end always starts with: `<img src="null"`

I want to replace it with nothing...just a blank space so that the other data is still useful.

So I tried running an update script, but I keep on getting this error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

This is my SQL UPDATE statement:

```
DECLARE @searchFor NVARCHAR(40) = N'%<img src="null"%';

UPDATE studentList
SET majorDescription = (SELECT LEFT(majorDescription , CHARINDEX(@searchFor, majorDescription ) - 1) FROM studentList)
WHERE majorDescription like N'%<img src="null"%'
```

I'm not sure why it's giving me that error.  I know there are 300+ rows because I can see them when I run this `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT majorDescription FROM studentList WHERE majorDescription like N'%<img src="null"%'
```

Is there anthing else I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: `I'm not sure why it's giving me that error` - because `charindex()` returns 0, so you end up passing `-1` to `left()`? You cannot expect this expression will only evaluate for rows that have `like N'%<img src="null"%'` The server may choose to evaluate it for all rows and then filter. Is this the actual code anyway? Your subquery appears to return all rows from the table for each row of the updated table.

Comment: @GSerg Oh ok, so I need to pass in 0 to the `left()`?  thanks!

Comment: Tip - you can avoid the error with a simple workaround by using `nullif`

Comment: @Stu How's that?

Comment: @gserg if you pass NULL as the length to the function it will return null and not error. Eg Left(string, nullif(expression-1,-1))

Comment: @Stu So I would use `SET majorDescription = (SELECT LEFT(majorDescription , nullif(@searchFor, (majorDescription - 1 ) - 1) FROM studentList)` ?Thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell That will certaintly prevent your query from generating the invalid length error.

Comment: @Stu thank you!  I will give that a try!

Comment: Have you thought about using the XML `.modify` function if you are trying to modify valid XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also add a "Fail-Safe" if the string can't be found.

Notice that I add concatenated `majorDescription+@searchFor` in the `charindex()`.

Also not clear why the `SET` was a `SELECT`

**Example**

```
DECLARE @searchFor NVARCHAR(40) = N'<img src="null"';

UPDATE studentList
SET majorDescription =  LEFT(majorDescription , CHARINDEX(@searchFor, majorDescription+@searchFor ) - 1) 
WHERE majorDescription like N'%'+@searchFor+'%'
```

Comment: Hi, this gets rid of the error but it doesn't update anything. It just says, `(0 rows affected)
`

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Does the condition not exists?   try Select * from studentList WHERE majorDescription like N'%'+@searchFor+'%'

Comment: I deleted  the last double quote in the `@searchFor` string and it worked!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Fabulous!  It is always the little things :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarity, an easy workaround would be to use `nullif` to pass a `null` as the length parameter.

Numerous functions in SQL Server will return `null` by design if a parameter is passed as null, which can be useful to avoid other more tedious workarounds, so you could try

```
SELECT LEFT(majorDescription, NullIf( CHARINDEX(@searchFor, majorDescription ) - 1, -1)) FROM studentList
```

Comment: This is giving me this error: `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '%<img src="null"%' to data type int.`

Comment: Should you have the `%` in your `@searchFor ` variable? See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b9f0ff82e9c41be40f2fe0b06e47d760) - seems to work ok?